# How to design a function which return a array of oid

Tags: c, libgit2

As already written at [issue#2217](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2217), I want to design a function which return a list of oid in the first out param.

Should I:

- Return the list of oids as a pointer to pointer?

`int git_commit_tree_last_commit_id(git_oid **out, git_repository *repo, const git_commit *commit, char *path)`

- Or return the list of oids as a pointer to a custom struct?

`int git_commit_tree_last_commit_id(git_oid_xx_struct *out, git_repository *repo, const git_commit *commit, char *path)`

What is your advice?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, how do you know how many OIDs are in the returned array, and who allocates the underlying memory.

For the first part there are several possibilities,

- Return the number in a separate return parameter,
- Use a sentinel value to terminate the list.
- Return a new struct type, like `git_strarray` that contains the count and the
  raw data.

For the second part, either

- the caller can allocate the underlying memory
- The function can allocate the memory
- the new struct type can manage the memory.

Which path you go down depends upon what you want the code to look like, how much you expect it to be reused, how critical performance is etc.

To start with I'd go with the simplest, which IMO is function returns count and allocates memory.

That means my function would have to look like this:

```
int get_some_oids_in_an_array(OID** array, int * count, ... ) {
  ...
  *count = number_of_oids;
  *array = (OID*)malloc( sizeof(OID)*number_of_oids);
  for(i=0; i<number_of_oids; ++i) {
    *array[i]=...;
  }
  ...
  return 0;
}

/* Example of usage */
void use_get_oids() {
  OID* oids;
  int n_oids;
  int ok = get_some_oids_in_an_array(&oids, &n_oids, ...);
  for(i=0; i<n_oids; ++i ) {
    ... use oids[i] ...
  }
  free(oids);
}
```

Note: I'm returning an array of OID, rather than an array of OID*, either is a valid option, and which will work best for you will vary.

If it turned out I was using this kind of pattern often, then would consider switching to the struct route.

```
int get_some_oids( oidarray * oids, ... ) {
  int i;
  oidarray_ensure_size(number_of_oids);
  for(i=0; i<number_of_oids; ++i) {
    oidarray_set_value(i, ...);
  }
  return 0;
}

typedef struct oidarray {
  size_t count;
  OID* oids;
};

/* Example of usage */
void use_get_oids() {
  oid_array oids = {0};
  get_some_oids(&oids);
  for(i=0; i<oids.count; ++i) {
    ... use oids.oids[i] ...
  }
  oidarray_release(&oids);
}
```